# Unable to pass string variable to JS date object

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to pass string variable to JS date object and create date in future.
Its easy to do in this way:

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var my_date = new Date(year + 1, month +1, day +1);
```

But how I can pass it with string variable, so that I can achieve something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var my_variable = 'year + 1, month +1, day +1';
var my_date = new Date(my_variable);
```

In this case it returns Invalid date

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work that way. Why do you have what is essentially Javascript code as a string as input?!

Comment: As @deceze says, it definitely doesn't work that way. You could use an `eval` statement?

Comment: string as input is required because I will pass there dynamic data

Comment: @freefaller Everytime you mention `eval` you should also use: `*WARNING* DO NOT USE EVAL`

Comment: @Dementic - absolutely agree, but can't think of an obvious other solution

Comment: In order to manipulate dates, I would recommend you to use libraries like

https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns

https://momentjs.com/
or others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: You need a bespoke parser. Not too difficult to write, just a bit tedious.

Comment: why don't you return with an object where you define the addition value? Like `obj = {addToYear: 1, addToMonth: 1, addToDay: 1}`. Then you only have to do eg `new Date (year + obj.addToYear, month + obj.addToMonth, day + obj.addToDay)`. If you want remove days, simply use `addToDay: -5` to remove 5 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**

You need to be a little careful with date arithmetic since it's not symmetric and may give odd results, e.g. 29 Feb 2016 + 1 year gives 1 March 2017, and 31 July minus 1 month is 1 July since there is no 31 June, it rolls over to July, and so on.

Given your original requirement, you might consider a parser for your particular format, e.g.

```js
function myParse(s, date) {
  date = date || new Date();
  // Default values object
  var values = {
    year:{sign:1, value:0}, month:{sign:1, value:0}, day:{sign:1, value:0}
  };
  // Tokenise string
  var part = s.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+|\d+|[+-]/ig);

  // Process the tokens
  if (part) {
    for (var i=0, iLen=part.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (part[i] in values) {
        values[part[i]].sign = part[i+1] == '+'? 1 : -1;
        values[part[i]].value = +part[i+2];
        i += 2;
      }
    }
  }
  // Apply to date
  date.setFullYear(
    date.getFullYear() + values.year.sign  * values.year.value,
    date.getMonth()    + values.month.sign * values.month.value,
    date.getDate()     + values.day.sign   * values.day.value
  );
  
  return date;
}

// Examples
var options = {day:'2-digit',month:'short',year:'numeric'};
console.log('Today is ' + (new Date().toLocaleString('en-gb', options)));

['year+1,month+1,day+1', // one of each
 'year+2,day+2',         // missing parameters
 'day  +  15, month +2', // any order, random whitespace
 'month - 3'             // subtraction

].forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + '\n' + myParse(s).toLocaleString('en-gb', options));
});
```

It's fairly tolerant but you should validate the input. It could be extended to handle time too, and also the end of month issues noted above.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting Javascript code as a string, which makes no sense to the Date class.

You can have your variables stored in an array to pass them elegantly to Date.

```
const dates = [year + 1, month +1, day +1]
const my_date = new Date(...dates);
```

I've read a follow up comment which indicates you'll only be getting strings from wherever you are retrieving the data from. Firstly if the string is in the format of 'year + 1, month + 1, day + 1', it'll never make sense to the Date object. If the string is just 3 numbers separated by a comma, you could split the string at the commas and pass them to the Date object in the same fashion.

```
const dates = myString.split(',');
const my_date = new Date(...dates);
```

Comment: I believe the *problem* is that the values are stored in a single string, not a series/array of useful values

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that with his follow up comments. If the strings are numbers separated by commas, he could just split the string at commas and parse each element into a number, then pass it to the Date object in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately javascript (and all the languages that I know off hand) do not work like that.

You could use an [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) statement instead, which allows you to create the entire instruction as a string and run that string...

```
var my_variable = 'year + 1, month +1, day +1';
eval('var my_date = new Date(' + my_variable + ');');
```

**HOWEVER** using of `eval` is dangerous, and could open you up to unexpected attacks.  Only use it if absolutely necessary, and if you're sure that the string being used is "safe"